# Investigating memory leak while using TMinuit ROOT with valgrind

Tags: memory-leaks, valgrind, root-framework, iminuit

I am using TMinuit in a loop for scanning some upper limit maps and I am running into a memory problem. The only thing which is created within the loop is the TMinuit object using "TMinuit * minuit = new TMinuit(n_params);". This is deleted at the end of the loop using "delete minuit". I used valgrind and it says something concerning Minuit (just a snippet here), but honestly, I don't understand that output. My guess was, that freeing memory is reached by "delete minuit". Obviously, that's not all.. Some suggestions? :-)

Valgrind output is here:

```
==17564== 46,053,008 (4,227,048 direct, 41,825,960 indirect) bytes in 25,161 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 11,738 of 11,738
==17564==    at 0x4C2E0EF: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17564==    by 0x52D77A8: TStorage::ObjectAlloc(unsigned long) (TStorage.cxx:330)
==17564==    by 0x403601B: ???
==17564==    by 0x4036064: ???
==17564==    by 0x914984F: TClingCallFunc::exec(void*, void*) (TClingCallFunc.cxx:1776)
==17564==    by 0x914A28F: operator() (functional:2267)
==17564==    by 0x914A28F: TClingCallFunc::exec_with_valref_return(void*, cling::Value*) (TClingCallFunc.cxx:1998)
==17564==    by 0x914AC58: TClingCallFunc::ExecInt(void*) (TClingCallFunc.cxx:2095)
==17564==    by 0x53468A8: TMethodCall::Execute(void*, long&) (TMethodCall.cxx:457)
==17564==    by 0x17DDFE20: Execute (TMethodCall.h:136)
==17564==    by 0x17DDFE20: ExecPluginImpl<int, double*, double*> (TPluginManager.h:162)
==17564==    by 0x17DDFE20: ExecPlugin<int, double*, double*> (TPluginManager.h:174)
==17564==    by 0x17DDFE20: TMinuit::mnplot(double*, double*, char*, int, int, int) (TMinuit.cxx:6085)
==17564==    by 0x17DE3C18: TMinuit::mnscan() (TMinuit.cxx:6803)
==17564==    by 0x17DF744D: TMinuit::mnexcm(char const*, double*, int, int&) (TMinuit.cxx:2977)
==17564==    by 0x17DD9235: TMinuit::mncomd(char const*, int&) (TMinuit.cxx:1382)
==17564==    by 0x178CA910: ULcoh(int, int) (in /mnt/scr1/user/j_blom02/analysis/phikk/ul/ulmaps_C.so)
==17564==    by 0x178CADA4: ulmaps(bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, int) (in /mnt/scr1/user/j_blom02/analysis/phikk/ul/ulmaps_C.so)
==17564==    by 0x4032084: ???
==17564==    by 0x918588B: cling::Interpreter::RunFunction(clang::FunctionDecl const*, cling::Value*) [clone .part.290] [clone .constprop.445] (in /mnt/scr1/user/bes3/root/build_v6_14_08/lib/libCling.so)
==17564==    by 0x918A362: cling::Interpreter::EvaluateInternal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cling::CompilationOptions, cling::Value*, cling::Transaction**, unsigned long) (in /mnt/scr1/user/bes3/root/build_v6_14_08/lib/libCling.so)
==17564==    by 0x918A60B: cling::Interpreter::process(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cling::Value*, cling::Transaction**, bool) (in /mnt/scr1/user/bes3/root/build_v6_14_08/lib/libCling.so)
==17564==    by 0x9217886: cling::MetaProcessor::process(llvm::StringRef, cling::Interpreter::CompilationResult&, cling::Value*, bool) (in /mnt/scr1/user/bes3/root/build_v6_14_08/lib/libCling.so)
==17564==    by 0x90FB3D9: HandleInterpreterException(cling::MetaProcessor*, char const*, cling::Interpreter::CompilationResult&, cling::Value*) (TCling.cxx:2060)
==17564==    by 0x911033D: TCling::ProcessLine(char const*, TInterpreter::EErrorCode*) (TCling.cxx:2177)
==17564==    by 0x91022A2: TCling::ProcessLineSynch(char const*, TInterpreter::EErrorCode*) (TCling.cxx:3053)
==17564==    by 0x5272649: TApplication::ExecuteFile(char const*, int*, bool) (TApplication.cxx:1157)
==17564==    by 0x52735F5: TApplication::ProcessLine(char const*, bool, int*) (TApplication.cxx:1002)
==17564==    by 0x4E4A183: TRint::ProcessLineNr(char const*, char const*, int*) (TRint.cxx:756)
==17564==    by 0x4E4B956: TRint::Run(bool) (TRint.cxx:416)
==17564==    by 0x400999: main (rmain.cxx:30)
```

Comment: Can't answer myself, but I imagine whoever is will be interested:
Are you using the `valgrind-root.supp` file that root ships to avoid false positives?

Comment: Are you sure you never `break` or even `continue` out of the loop iteration, skipping the `delete minuit`, which would result in `minuit` going out of scope and thus there will be no more pointers for the memory you dynamically allocated for your `TMinuit` instance? This would explain the memory leak, because your program loses the address of your allocated memory, also losing the ability to free it. Anyway, try replacing `TMinuit * minuit = new TMinuit(n_params);` with `std::unique_ptr<TMinuit> minuit = std::make_unique<TMinuit>(n_params);` (that is if you use `ROOT 6` of course).

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your replies. I solved the problem!
See this link: https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/investigating-memory-leak-while-using-tminuit-root-with-valgrind/39164/2

Comment: @Johannes: Can you post an answer here? You can self-accept.